# Group several UIButtons into a single button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is it possible to wrap several controls/buttons into a single button where all buttons react (highlight/unhighlight) to presses on any of the elements, and all share the same action?

I'd like to have multiple "parts" (mainly labels and icons) of a button that I can control the layout for individually, but I want them to all behave as a single button and highlight all of the parts when tapped.

Perhaps I could track the pressed state of each button and make all the other components have the same state?

Comment: Connect them to the same IBAction and give tags in Inteface Builder.Then make a switch case statement on these tags? I think I misunderstood what you asked?

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the little dot to multiple buttons in your view and all those buttons will run the same IBAction code.

[image: IBAction Connector]

If you want to differentiate between them, you can use tags in interface builder and then call upon those tags with `[sender tag]`

[image: Tag]

So your IBAction could look a little like this:

```
- (IBAction)button_myButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([sender tag] == 0) {
        // This will run for button tag 0
    }

    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        // This will run for button tag 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was more interested in the highlighting of them all together though. Any thoughts on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I would put your buttons in an array and then use a fast enumeration for loop to run `[buttonAtIndex setSelected:YES];` on every button (where `buttonAtIndex` is what you declare in the for-in loop). You can do all that above the first if statement in the IBAction and It'll run with every button press to any button attached to that IBAction.

Comment: Awesome I will give it a shot!

Comment: Anytime! let me know if that worked out for you and if it did, you can mark the question as answered. Thanks!